# Issue during update-grub

Tags: grub2

Similar question have been previously asked ,i have gone through them without any solution, that is why i am posting a new one.

I have built and installed a new kernel (compiled from source) using the generic config file available in /boot
after installing the kernel, I run the following command

```
sudo update-grub
```

at which i receive this message

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: 10: not found
```

I inspected into the issue, in /etc/default/grub the line number 10 reads

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

I found out that there was no **LSB release**, and so i installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

strangely the 6th line in the file **grub-mkconfig** is a comment. after this i am clueless as to what to do..
any hints would be highly appreciated.

Here is my /etc/default/grub file
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7717187/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7717187/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before the `10` in `GRUB_DEFAULT= 10`. Variable assignments in shell scripts should not have any space after the `=`. The `/etc/default/grub` file is essentially a shell script sourced by `grub-mkconfig`,  so it must comply with shell syntax.
The absence of `lsb_release` can never cause an error in grub configuration ordinary circumstances, since the `2> /dev/null || echo Debian` part pretty much ensures no error message is output.